# How to I place the create form for content type on a page that can save the user's id?

Tags: views, forms

I'm new to Drupal. I've created a content type and I've created a view (using the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module) to display the data.

I can add data from `Content > Add Content > Item`, which gives you a Drupal admin form.

How do I place this form on a page that can save the user's id?

Comment: What do you mean by "place this form on a page that can save the user's id"? Do you want to save the editing user's id in a field of that form? Can you elaborate on what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: For the form, I don't want to use the modal window that comes with Drupal, I want a form for logged in users to add items to the items content type. How do I create a page, items/add-new-item and have a form on that page that saves content to the items content type? thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, to get rid of the "modal window", go to `admin/modules` and disable the **Overlay** module.

Second, if you want your logged in users to be able to create articles:

1. Go to `admin/people/permissions` and scroll down to the *Node* section.
2. There you will find different options to grant them *Create*, *Edit*, *Delete*, etc. permissions. For example, you can check ***Article: Create new content*** under the ***Authenticated User*** column to allow them to add new items in the *Article* content type.

Now your logged-in users can go to `node/add/article` page to find the form.

Comment: Thank you :) - I think I'm looking for a theme hook maybe? I want to have non admin page for logged in users to add content, or do you style the admin page /node/add/item to look like your template?

Comment: Try what I suggested. If you access node/add/article **as a logged in user** (not as an admin), you will see your website's theme, not your admin theme. You only see your admin theme when you are logged in with your administrator's account.